# set formatprg dynamically based on textwidth?

Tags: formatting, options

I've set `formatprg` in my vimrc to use the [par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) text formatter when I type **`gq`**.

```
setg formatprg=par\ -w90
```

When I'm in a buffer whose `textwidth` has been set (e.g. the gitcommit filetype sets `textwidth=72`), I'd like to use that number rather than 90.

Instead of hard-coding different values in a bunch of ftplugin files, I'd like to compute the number dynamically upon usage.

I took a look at `formatexpr`, but if I set a formatexpr it would also be called whenever I enter characters beyond the textwidth line length, and I don't think I'd want to call out to an external process that frequently.

The only other solutions I can think of are writing a wrapper around **`gq`** (which I imagine would get complex if I want to support operating-pending mode correctly) and adding an autocmd that listens for the Filetype event and sets `formatprg` appropriately. That last solution seems the most reasonable, actually.

I'm curious if there's another option I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 4):

That's when the [`OptionSet`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#OptionSet) event comes in handy, but it doesn't work when it's triggered on startup so you need the  [`VimEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter) event too.

If your workflow includes several files opened in different windows/buffers, with different `textwidth` values, you can include the [`BufEnter`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufEnter) event to adjust `formatprg` (a global option)  according to the `textwidth` of the current window/buffer.

You could put the following code at the end of your `vimrc` file:

```
setg formatprg=par\ -w90

function! UpdateFormatprg()
   let &g:formatprg = substitute( &g:formatprg , '\d\+$', &textwidth , "" )
endfunction

augroup UpdateFormatprgGroup
   autocmd!
   autocmd VimEnter,BufEnter * call UpdateFormatprg()
   autocmd OptionSet textwidth call UpdateFormatprg()
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add this in `ftplugin/gitcommit.vim`:

```
" setlocal textwidth=72
let &l:formatprg = 'par -w' . &l:textwidth
```

Or using an auto command, just make sure `&textwidth` is correctly set before the FileType event:

```
augroup FormatPrg
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType gitcommit let &l:formatprg = 'par -w' . &l:textwidth
augroup END
```

Comment: I ended up writing a function that returns `&tw > 0 ? &tw : 90` and adding an autocmd that executes `setl formatprg=par\ -w'.GetTextWidth()`

Comment: Be careful, `set` and `setlocal` expect a string, thus not evaluating variables. You want the alternative form `let &l:` (or `let &` for global variables). For more details, check `:h set-args` and `:h let-&`.

Comment: The actual autocmd is `autocmd FileType * execute 'setl formatprg=par\ -w'.GetTextWidth()`

Comment: I am curious, is there a reason for using `execute 'setlocal ...'` over `let &l:...`?